# Documentation for a system of related C++ programs

Tags: c++, bash, documentation, doxygen

I've written a bunch of different related programs that primarily run on Linux. These programs are a mix of C++ programs and bash scripts. I'd like to document this system by placing a high-level description of each executable at the top of the source file (in the case of C++ programs) and within the script files themselves (in the case of bash scripts). I started looking at Doxygen but it seems that this tool is optimized to show the interfaces in C++ classes and functions and it was not immediately obvious to me how the system might be used to generate higher-level documentation. Is there a better tool than Doxygen for this task, or how can I use Doxygen to do what I want? I'm not opposed to documenting the functions and classes with Doxygen but that's not my primary purpose.

Comment: I think you can use doxygen for this task, e.g. the doxygen manual is also generated with doxygen. You have also commands like `\page`, `\section` etc available so you can add your text as comment on top of the file. Just have a go at it and when there are problems show a small example of what you would like to accomplish and where it goes wrong.

Comment: If you are distributing for others - shouldn't you produce man pages? or info pages? [you can put the stuff in the header - and write a script to extract...]